# C++ algorithm exercise

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a question about one of my problems.
I have an array with n elements and I must see if this one is made by this rule:
positive negative positive positive negative negative positive positive positive negative negative negative 
Here is my code:
    // Sa se verifice daca un vector contine elementele in ordinea:
// pozitiv-negativ-pozitiv-pozitiv-negativ-negativ-pozitiv-pozitiv-pozitiv etc.
// Se va afisa DA sau NU.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i, j, k;
int n;
cout<<"Dati numarul de elemente: ";
cin>>n;
int v[n+1];
cout<<"Dati elementele vectorului: ";
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    cin>>v[i];

int stop = 1;
int aici = 2;
int pozitiv, negativ;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i+stop)
{
    for(int k=i; k<=aici/2; k++)
    {
        cout<<"v[k] = "<<v[k]<<endl;
        if(v[k]>0)
            pozitiv = 1;
        else
        { 
            pozitiv = 0;
            break;
        } 
    }
    for(int j=aici/2+1; j<=aici; j++)
    {
        cout<<"v[j] = "<<v[j]<<endl;
        if(v[j]<0)
            negativ = 1;
        else
        { 
            negativ = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pozitiv == 0 && negativ == 0)
        break;
    stop = 2*i;
    aici = aici + stop;
    cout<<stop<<" "<<aici<<endl;
}

if(pozitiv == 1 && negativ == 1)
    cout<<endl<<"DA!";
else cout<<endl<<"NU!";

cout<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have an array and I must see if is made by this rule. My code didn't work

Comment: "*My code didn't work*" Okay....what went wrong? What were you expecting and what happened? There are thousands of questions posted each day, very few of the brilliant minds here on SO will take the time to try and decipher your code for you with none of that information.

Comment: @Vader I'd like to know what is your native language?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i think he is русский

Comment: Sorry for my bad question, is the first one on this site.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Is there some significant pattern disturbung the translation from one particular language to another (english as it's required for questions here)?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah  I am sure that it is not Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sign(int v)
{
   return (v == 0) ? 0 : ((v > 0) ? 1 : -1);
}

int check(int v[], int n) // return 1 for true, 0 for false
{
   int sign = 1;
   int count = 1;
   int sc = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      if (sign(v[i]) != sign)
         return 0;
      sc++;
      if (sc == count)
      {
         sc = 0;
         if (sign == 1)
            sign = -1;
         else
         {
            sign = 1;
            count++;
         }
      }
   }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
   // ... put here your code for filling v

   cout << (check(v, n)) ? "DA!" : "NU!" << endl;
}
```

Also, you should declare v as int v[n], and fill it from v[0] to v[n-1].